# Amazon S3 images not showing on Linkedin or Facebook status update

Tags: facebook, image, amazon-s3, thumbnails, linkedin-api

I have image URL from Amazon S3 - https://s3.amazonaws.com/goodco_api_staging/private/cards/company_fit_score/5512ba766472655d211d0000-54010bdd69702d4155040100.png
When I try to share this URL on linkedin status update I do not see image thumbnail [image]

The same with Facebook. But other images work fine.
I think that image was not uploaded correctly on S3, but I do not know what is missed.

Could you point me what can be wrong with the image or how I can validated it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about programming. Even if you were directed here by LinkedIn support, your question must still be on-topic by StackOverflow's rules: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281019/reach-out-to-linkedin-about-outsourcing-their-developer-support-to-stack-overflo

Comment: If you read the answer, its about programming, as the mistake I was doing there was not setting correct mime-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the mime-type of the response header, is it of image type?

Comment: This is not a solution to the posed question. Downvoted.